# DAX express to pull data from unrelated table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 4 tables:

Fact Table: Subtasks_time_tracking
columns: [subtask_id], [task_id], [project_id], [time_spent]

Dimension table 1: Subtasks
columns: [subtask_id], [task_id], [subtask_name]

Dimension table 2: Tasks
columns: [task_id], [project_id]

Dimension table 3: Projects
columns: [project_id], [project_name]

Tables 1, 2, 3 are connect to 'Fact Table' through subtask_id, task_id, and project_id respectively.

Tables 1, 2, 3 are not connect to each other and NOT REQUIRED TO BE CONNECTED DIRECTLY.

Requirement: I want to pull the column [project_name] from the 'Projects' table against each [subtask_name] through DAX code.

So far I have been able to pull the [project_id] from the Tasks table through the following DAX code.

Project = CALCULATE(
SELECTEDVALUE(Tasks[project_id]),TREATAS(VALUES(Subtasks[task_id]),Tasks[task_id]))

How can I go one step further and pull the [project_name] from the Projects table?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix and clarify if it is a measure or calculated column you want?

Comment: I need a DAX measure, not a column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your datamodel looks something like this: [image: Datamodel]

However I would recommend to join your dimension tables into 1 or 2 tables. If you join them in power query you won't have to do any dax and make your life a whole lot easier.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query, I will check this approach to see if it works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: However, is there any way to pull the project name from the Projects table through DAX code, as was my original question?

Comment: There shouln't be any DAX needed to get the Project name into visuals. Can you show a screenshot of what is happing with one of the datamodels above?